# Azerothcore sql assembler script isnt working

Tags: azerothcore

I followed the instructions in
https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Database-Setup

[keep getting this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mqmP.png)

my OS is windows 10

Comment: please include more details in your question, such as: the command you are trying to execute, the error that you get, your AC version, etc... the screenshot is NOT enough, we need the information as text too.

Comment: AC version is d50793535e0a. The command im executing is mysql -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';" -u root -p, since im using mysql 5.7. Then I execute bash apps/db_assembler/db_assembler.sh in the azerothcore directory and I selected import-all: Assemble & Import all. I did put the config.sh in conf folder, changed the variables accordingly in config.sh to match my server user and pass.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a space in your username. From my understanding the db_assembler.sh does not currently support spaces in the path. I would suggest moving your azerothcore source folder to a different directory.